# Google Maps in a Webview for Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-maps, webview

I have a pair of questions about google maps for android. I decided to use a webview to display google maps due to the compatibility for the google maps api, so i'm having problems with really simple things (at least i think the are simple).

1) At the start of the application, my webview shows the map with a very low zoom. How can i set a higher zoom from the beginning? There are +/- buttons, but they are pretty uncomfortable.

2) How can i put a mark on the map? With the api, i have just to use the

> google.maps.Marker

, but i don't know ho to use it with a webview.
I think that both the problems can be solved using javascript, but i'm new and i really don't know how to solve them. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the marker, you could create a javascript function to add a marker, and then on the WebView load a url like `javascript:addAMarker("AddItHere");`. I don't get what you mean the buttons are uncomfortable for the +/-.

Comment: I'd like to get a very high zoom level for my application, but at the beginning the zoom is very low, so i have to press + to reach a decent zoom level

Comment: Using javascript you can set the initial zoom level using mapOptions see here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial maybe that will help